# How can I get my header fitting right across

Tags: css

I have been redesigning the header on www.adultsonlyholidays.co.uk. The issue i am having is the header is not sitting all the way across or right to the top. If you look at the left you will see there appears to be some padding but I cannot see where from. Here is my css:

```
.greyStrip1 { width:100%; height:55px; background:#222222; position: fixed;}
```

Comment: There is no element with `greyStrip1` in its class list on that site.

Comment: `body { margin: 0 }`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `body` to `margin:0`

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
}
```